# What is the cause of difference between "Complete" version and "Custom version" with "All Foundation Components"?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Is there any difference between `"Complete"` version (In the top section close to the "Essential", "Custom" and "Sass" link) and `"Customize Foundation/custom version"` with `"All Foundation Components"`in [Foundation download page](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/)?

See below images, please:
[image]
 **With**:
[image]

I want to download the latest version of foundation 6+ completely with full components of it, but it seems there are many differences between these two versions just in `LTR` Languages without considering the `RTL` matter (for example in style of buttons and width of rows and etc).

Button style in **Complete** version:
[image]

and that button in **Custom** version:
[image]

As you can see the `background-color` and `color` (text-color) and `border-radius` are different, But both of them are in RTL (6.3.1) version.

Note: I compared and tested both those versions in `LTR` direction.

I will be grateful if anyone explain the cause of difference between those versions and explain which one of them is more complete and reliable?

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is RTL language support you should choose either Custom Download (and select appropriate text direction) or Sass.

Custom Download gets you running quickly with just the end result JavaScript and CSS files.

Sass is the entire pipeline: build, Scss, ES6, unit tests, etc.  And yes, you can configure RTL using the Sass version too.  It's just a configuration change.

Also, the Sass version allows you to optionally work with latest set of changes from Zurb and the community.  You know, fixes and features that have not been made into an official release.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I appreciate you a lot, but what's the cause of differences between `LTR` versions without considering the `RTL` matter. What's more reliable `Complete` version or `Custom version` with `All Foundation Components`.

Comment: Both should be the same.  At the end of the day, Sass is the most reliable because you have complete control.

Comment: I tested and compered both `LTR` versions, There are many difference between them for example in style of buttons and width of rows and etc.